# Can someone please explain how to hook up this transformer?

Tags: transformer, identification

I found an old transformer that I purchased about 10 years ago to build a  regulated dual rail power supply, but never went through with the project.  I still would like to do the project but it has been so long now that I lost any documentation I might have had on this transformer.

Here is a picture of the markings on it and the various leads.  I am not sure which ones to hook up where.  If it helps, the bottom right lead is labeled 1 and the bottom left lead is 4.  Can someone please help me understand how this transformer should be hooked up?

[image: transformer image]

I did research "P241-5" and received a few hits on "quick connect" transformers, but the 36 threw me for a loop, because I think I was after a 12vac stepdown solution.  Could this be a *single 115v* 36vac, .35A transformer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the part number is P241-5-36 (I can't quite make it out from the picture), then your suggestion is correct.

115 volt primary, 36 volt center-tapped secondary, .35 Amp.

The two lower terminals (closest to the mounting tabs) would be the primary, with the upper terminals being the secondary.